# R, how to plot multiple plots in the same image after a loop by using ggplot2?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a script in R that creates different plots in the same loop, by using ggplot2. When the loop ends up, I would like it to print all the plots in a unique image.

This is how code looks like:

```
dim = 6;
vectPlot = c();
for (i in 1:dim)
{
  vectPlot[i] = qplot(...) 
}
```

I need something like a `printManyPlotsInOneImage(vectPlot)' function. I tried with`multiplot()' but did not work (nothing happens).

Do you know how I could deal with this?

UPDATE: I need the input of the qplot() function to change as well inside the loop.
The program is something like this:

```
dim = 6;
vectPlot = c();
dataArray = read.table(....)
for (i in 1:dim)
{
  vectPlot[i] = qplot(dataArray[i],...) 
}
```

How could I use lapply efficiently in this case?

Comment: See my updated answer! I edited my earliet answer as well. I was only assigning "6" to dim2 instead of 1:6. fixed that. Now lapply will "loop" over the sequence assigned to dim2

Answer (score 1):

Edited your code to assign plots to a list

```
dim2 = 1:6 #don't use dim, it's buil-in funtion
vecPlot= lapply(dim2,
                function(x) qplot(rnorm(20,x), 
                main = paste0("Histogram with mean = ",x))) 
                #modify qplot as appropriate
```

you can do multiplot, but since your plots are in list, it's not working.
try this to make multiplot execute over the list

```
do.call(multiplot, vecPlot)
```

I suggest reading `?do.call` to understand better what's going on.
For finer control, with ncols, nrows (dictating how many columns and rows of plots you want and maybe a common title) use grid.arrage from the package gridExtra. you will need to install this package 
try this

```
library(gridExtra)
do.call(grid.arrange,vecPlot)
```

And finally to answer your updated question

```
dim2 = 1:6;
dataArray = read.table(....)
vecPlot = lapply(dim2, function(x) {
      qplot(dataArray[x],...) 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately they both do not work. grid.arrange() generates this error: `Error in arrangeGrob(..., as.table = as.table, clip = clip, main main,  :  input must be grobs! Calls: histogramGenerator -> do.call -> <Anonymous> -> grid.draw -> arrangeGrob In addition: There were 12 warnings (use warnings() to see them) Execution halted', while multiplot() printed a lot of data lines but produced no image

Comment: I see, but what's the sense of function(x) and rnorm()? Thanks

Comment: read `?"function" and `?rnorm` for details. rnorm generates random numbers with a normal distn with mean x. and I defined a custom function to pass to lapply. you can also read this http://www.statmethods.net/management/userfunctions.html for more on functions

Comment: I see, thanks. But this way I'm not able to cycle on the vector list I need to use. Lapply seems to apply the function always to the same parameter, while it should change in my case. I'll update the question.